# Register content provider dynamically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to register a content provider dynamically? What I mean is that I don't want to write anything about content provider in manifest. I want to register from my java code ifself. Is it possible? If yes How to do this?

Comment: no, they need to be declared in the manifesto

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to register a content provider dynamically. We have to define it in Manifest only. Thanks to @pskink